# How to create lock alert modal in pages in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I wanted to create a modal that pops up on screen if access is still locked on specific pages in React.js application even if it has direct change on URL. I don't have any idea how to approach that when a user types the route, it would still prevent him accessing the page for a period of time.
Example routes: `/products/1`
When I access a route by clicking a button, I could do the checking in onClick event. But when the user types the route in the URL directly, page can be accessed. In what ways can I prevent the user from accessing the page if it is direct modified in the URL? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Wrapper component for those routes where you want to check if the visitor/user has access to the page. Are you using React Router? Then this link can help you to set up a protected route - https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

Specifically the following code,

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  let auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

The example for authentication checks on private routes but you can follow the same architecture for checking the user access permission.

Also, if you want to show a modal on the page you can check the access permission using the `useEffect` hook for functional components or `componentDidMount` on class-based components.